# Entering Infinite Loop in Authentication Filter in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to make a GET request within a custom authentication filter I've made in Spring, but seem to be entering an infinite loop.  Basically, I want to make a GET request with a username and check whether this username is authenticated on a separate server with implementation in Python.

After removing the GET request, it seems to work.  Is it applying the filter to the URL I create in the code?  How can I get around this, if so?

```
            String authURL = request.getScheme() + "://" + "test-app";
            authURL += "/test/authenticate_user?ui_user=" + http_request.getParameter("ui_user");

            System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + authURL);

            try {
                sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                sslContext.init(null,
                        trustAllCerts,
                        new SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
                URL auth_obj = new URL(null, authURL, new Handler());
                System.out.println(authURL);
                auth_con = (HttpsURLConnection) auth_obj.openConnection();
                auth_con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                auth_con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            if (true) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(auth_con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("", null,
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                chain.doFilter(http_request, http_response);
            }
```

Comment: You should log the `inputLine` in your while and see if your infinit loop is there. If not, add some log elsewhere to find out the where it is

Comment: It's not.  It will pass the chain.doFilter line and hang.  To add to my post, this will work on a locally deployed server, but not when I deploy to a cloud service.  The inputLine is what it's supposed to be.

Comment: But how do you know that it's an infinite loop ?

Comment: When I hit the endpoint, it will try to load the page for about 20 seconds and then gives me a 502 error.

Comment: Then it's probably because of your `GET` request. Look at the complete url, it's probably incorrect